# Permutations of Even number of Odd Cycles

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am looking to show that the number of permutations on $n$ objects such that there are an even number of cycles, all with odd length, is equal to
$${n \choose {n/2}}\frac{n!}{2^n}$$   
if $n$ is even and $0$ otherwise

---

In my search about how to go about this problem, I have found a number of sites describing the difference between an odd and an even permutation (odd: number of even length cycles is odd, even: number of even length cycles is even). However, I am not sure how to go about it for odd length cycles.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Well if $n$ is odd and there were an even number of odd cycles we get a contradiction, for a contribution of zero. If $n$ is even the number of odd length cycles must be even, for a contribution of $n!.$

Comment: Sorry, I did forget to specify that n should be even!

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Note that for $n$ even, the condition is that all cycles have odd length.  It's stronger than just having an even number of odd-length cycles, which is all permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Combinatorial class

Using combinatorial classes we have the following class $\mathcal{P}$ 
of permutations with all cycles of odd length:
  
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(
\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=5}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the EGF

$$G(z) = 
\exp\left(z+\frac{z^3}{3} + \frac{z^5}{5} + \cdots\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}
- \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{1}{1-z^2}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \sqrt{1-z^2}.$$

#### Recurrence

Now we have

$$G'(z) = G(z) \frac{1}{1-z} - G(z) \frac{z}{1-z^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} G(z) \frac{1}{1-z}
+ \frac{1}{2} G(z) \frac{1}{1+z}.$$

Extracting coefficients we get a recurrence for $G_n = [z^n] G(z)$
where the desired quantity is $n! \times G_n$ and $G_0 = G_1 = 1$

$$[z^n] G'(z) = (n+1) G_{n+1} =
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^n G_q
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^n G_q (-1)^{n-q}$$

We also have

$$(n+3) G_{n+3} =
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^{n+2} G_q
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^{n+2} G_q (-1)^{n-q}$$

which yields

$$(n+3) G_{n+3} - (n+1) G_{n+1} =
\frac{1}{2} (G_{n+1} + G_{n+2})
+ \frac{1}{2} ( - G_{n+1} + G_{n+2} )$$

so that

$$(n+3) G_{n+3} = G_{n+2} + (n+1) G_{n+1}.$$

#### Induction proof of closed form

We now claim that for $n\ge 0$ we have

$$G_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2^n} {n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}.$$

We will prove this by induction. We have two consecutive base cases for
$n=0$ and $n=1$ which go through, being confirmed combinatorially. Now
if $n=2m$ we need to verify that

$$(2m+3) \frac{1}{2^{2m+2}} {2m+2\choose m+1}
= \frac{1}{2^{2m+1}} {2m+1\choose m} 
+ (2m+1) \frac{1}{2^{2m}} {2m\choose m}.$$

Multiply by $(m+1)!^2$ to get

$$(2m+3)!/2^{2m+2} = 
(m+1) (2m+1)!/2^{2m+1} + (m+1)^2 (2m+1)!/2^{2m}$$

Now we have $(2m+3)(2m+2) = 2(m+1)+4(m+1)^2$ so this holds.
Next when $n=2m+1$ we need

$$(2m+4)\frac{1}{2^{2m+3}} {2m+3\choose m+1}
= \frac{1}{2^{2m+2}} {2m+2\choose m+1} 
+ (2m+2) \frac{1}{2^{2m+1}} {2m+1\choose m}.$$

Multiply by $(m+1)! (m+2)!$ to get

$$(2m+4)!/2^{2m+3} = 
(m+2) (2m+2)!/2^{2m+2} + (m+1) (m+2) (2m+2)!/2^{2m+1}$$

This time we have $(2m+4)(2m+3) = 2(m+2) + 4(m+1)(m+2)$
so this holds as well. This completes the induction proof.

#### Conclusion

Keeping in mind that we seek $n!\times G_n$ we have shown
the closed form for $n\ge 1$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}} {n-1\choose \lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}.}$$

This yields the sequence

$$1, 1, 3, 9, 45, 225, 1575, 11025, 99225, 893025, \ldots$$

which points us to [OEIS A000246](https://oeis.org/A000246), where a
variety of additional material  awaits.

#### Remark

As regards how we interpret the question, we say that the permutation            must consist of an even number of cycles, all of which are odd. This is          only  possible for $n$ even. (Moreover if there are only odd cycles              there must be an even number of them.) In that case the  the closed form         will produce
                                                                                                                                                      $$\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}} {n-1\choose n/2-1}                                          = \frac{n!}{2^{n-1}} \frac{n/2}{n} {n\choose n/2}                                = \frac{n!}{2^n} {n\choose n/2}$$
                                                                                                                                 as proposed by OP. We get zero for $n$ odd, again as proposed by OP.             Here the above boxed formula gives the number of permutations                    consisting of an odd number of odd cycles.

Comment: How did you get the result change from the last line of Combinatorial Class to the first line of Recurrence? (Also, how does that turn into what is the second line in Recurrence)?

Comment: Differentiate using the product rule. Use partial fractions.